# Where are all the skulls and Intel located throughout the halo 5 campaign?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

The question says it all.  Throughout the campaign, where are all the skulls and Intel located ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This video goes over very much in depth how to get all 13 skulls, and getting the Achievement Gravelord (for getting all the skulls).  Since describing where to get them is very hard to do in words, the video should explain how to get them, posted below is the mission each skull can be found in, as well as where the intel is located.

> Missions:
>
> - **Mission 1** (*Osiris*) - IWHBYD Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qi6OdPh7FGw)
> - **Mission 2** (*Blue Team*) - Black Eye Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl3txS1276w)
> - **Mission 3** (*Glassed*) - Iron Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ty-_iaylasY)
> - **Mission 4** (*Meridian Station*) - N/A
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mX2TpZCyns)
> - **Mission 5** (*Unconfirmed*)  - Blind Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtMkTeaiAdY)
> - **Mission 6** (*Evacuation*)  - Thunderstorm Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gR8li3s58M)
> - **Mission 7** (*Reunion*)  - Grunt Birthday Party Skull
> - **Mission 7** (*Reunion*)  - Cloud Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDDIa3h92O0)
> - **Mission 8** (*Swords of Sanghelios*)  - Mythic Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2FaSD2EcFA)
> - **Mission 9** (*Alliance*) - N/A
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8BaFnzAA30)
> - **Mission 10** (*Enemy Lines*)  - Catch Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB_S6yamliM)
> - **Mission 11** (*Before the Storm*) - N/A
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bra8d0ywL3U)
> - **Mission 12** (*The Battle of Sunaion*)  - Cowbell Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfJcyP8q7Jk)
> - **Mission 13** (*Genesis*)  - Tilt Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYbM-uUTgrU)
> - **Mission 14** (*The Breaking*)  - Famine Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1IbEg75zvA)
> - **Mission 15** (*Guardians*)  - Tough Luck Skull
>
>   - [Intel Locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvDZk7PgTaA)